# WSO2 Proxy service XML Xpath

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

Im using wso2 EI  6.5.0 
in my proxy service i need to get element between these 2 tags `<aa></aa>`

**xpath //tem:Request is working but /tem:Request/xDoc/aa does not work**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <tem:Request>
             <xDoc>
                <aa>
                   <bb>
                        ....
                   </bb>
                   <cc>
                      <Parameter>
                        ......
                      </Parameter>
                   </cc>
                </aa>
             </xDoc>
          </tem:Request>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use either **/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/tem:Request/xDoc/aa** or **$body/tem:Request/xDoc/aa**.

The purpose of using "//" in an xpath is to directly access a particular element. But if we use "/", we need to specify the entire path to traverse through the XML tags and reach a particular element.

On a different note, if you want to access the tag `<aa/>` then you can directly use the xpath **//aa**.

Comment: thank u but it is not working, i constructed this it returns when print using xpath XML from inline script, it is between just A body tag but envelope
<soapenv:Body>.....</soapenv:Body>, how can i save it to property and get <aa> element, i set it to payload xml inside <root>$1</root>, so i need to retrieve it like 
/soapenv:Body/root/soapenv:Body/tem:Request/xDoc/aa
$body/tem:Request/xDoc/aa - none of this works